# Having trouble getting html from after a button is clicked/WebDriverWait is timing out when the condition is clearly met

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape https://www.broadwayworld.com/grosses/A-BEAUTIFUL-NOISETHE-NEIL-DIAMOND-MUSICAL but I want the html from after the "Show All" button is clicked. I know that the click command works because I can see the table change in the browser and if I access the class of the button afterward, it added 'active' to the end of the string. But when I try to grab the data from the table after that, it is still the same. I'm not sure if this can be solved without a wait but if not, I need help with that.

I added an explicit wait in case it just needed a second but the wait keeps timing out no matter how long I make it. Here is my code for the wait.

```
url = 'https://www.broadwayworld.com/grosses/A-BEAUTIFUL-NOISETHE-NEIL-DIAMOND-MUSICAL'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('https://www.broadwayworld.com/grosses/A-BEAUTIFUL-NOISETHE-NEIL-DIAMOND-MUSICAL')
driver.get(url)
gross_data = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'all-gross-data')
button = gross_data.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', button)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn btn-red show-all-grosses active')))
```

And this is without the wait (which still only gives the data from the table before the button was clicked):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
gross_data = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'all-gross-data')
button = gross_data.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', button)
after_click = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'table-body')
after_click = after_click.get_attribute('outerHTML')
print(after_click)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code, added scrolling Show all button before clicking and added wait for table to loaf

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import TimeoutException, MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
data = []
url = 'https://www.broadwayworld.com/grosses/A-BEAUTIFUL-NOISETHE-NEIL-DIAMOND-MUSICAL'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
action = ActionChains(driver)
# Close AD
try:
    adButton = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[text()="AD - CLICK HERE TO CLOSE"]')))
    adButton.click()
except TimeoutException as t:
    print("Ignoring as Sometimes ad doesn't show up")

showAllButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Show All"]')

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});",showAllButton)
time.sleep(2)

showAllButton.click()
# Wait for new table to load
time.sleep(5)

table = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "table")

tableHeader = table.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="table-header"]')
cells = tableHeader.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "cell")

header = []
for cell in cells:
    header.append(cell.text)

data.append(header)

tableBody = table.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='table-body']")

rows = tableBody.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "row")
for row in rows:
    tableCells = row.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "cell")
    newRow = []
    for cell in tableCells:
        newRow.append(cell.text)
    data.append(newRow)
driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("sam.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

outputs csv like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to avoid clicking any element via JavaScript injection. If you need to click on an element just use element.click()
2. Finding element by CSS will usually fail if you string has white spaces. If your class name is class="This is my class" you can use this CSS via (*=) which means contains:

   CSS=*[class*="This"][class*="my"][class*="is"]

Comment: Thanks! I initially tried using .click() and it wasn't working but that explains why.